# Netsuite: How to insert an iframe on post call

Tags: netsuite

I have written a suitelet which has two parts - GET and POST.
 In GET method I have a  dropdown and a submit button.
 In POST method, I have 5 text fields which display the data based on value fetched from dropdown in GET.

I want to call an iframe on submit button click. iframe will show POST method logic. In short, I don't want to navigate to new page on submit, but to make the whole thing work on a single page.

**MY CODE**

```
function init(request, response)
{
    if(request.getMethod() == 'GET')
    {
                //... some code for dropdown and submit

               //code for iframe
               var context = nlapiGetContext();

               var url = 'https://**url-of-post-method-results**.com';
           var title = context.getSetting('SCRIPT', 'custscript_suitelet_title')
               var content = '<iframe width=960px height=100% style="height:640px;" src=' + url + '></iframe>'

        var newField = form.addField ('content', 'inlinehtml', title);
        form.addField('extra', 'inlinehtml', '')
        form.setTitle (title);
        newField.setLayoutType('outsidebelow');
        newField.setDefaultValue (content);
        form.addSubmitButton('Submit');
        response.writePage(form);
}
```

}

I referred to [Marty Zigman's tutorial on embedding iframe](http://blog.prolecto.com/2012/04/25/draw-external-html-pages-within-netsuite/). But I'. confused where to embed the iframe, in GET or POST?

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, NetSuite has no built in way via their API to avoid a page refresh in a case like this. Clicking the submit button, will by default, submit the form via a post method synchronously. You need to interrupt the click() event method via jQuery on NetSuite's default form submit button using client side code. You would then send the post yourself using jQuery, and on a response, show the information you would like, again via jQuery, by updating the iframe src url.

I apologize I do not have currently have access to an account to be able to give you the appropriate JavaScript. I would be cautious of breakage though since you will need to hack into the NetSuite UI a bit to make this work.

Comment: Basically this, though instead of using interruptions is easier to just send back on get a fake form to do the ajax handling.